# Swift3 iOS -Firebase How to Separate Node Data Into Different Arrays and Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, dictionary, firebase

```
root
  |
  @-clothing
      |
      @-nameBrandRalphLauren//topLevel
      |  |
      |  @-apparelTops//child
      |  |    |-"garmetSweater":"white"
      |  |    |-"garmetTshirt":"blue"
      |  |    |-"postedBy":"user123"
      |  |
      |  @-apparelBottoms//child
      |       |-"garmetShorts":"tan"
      |       |-"garmetJeans":"blue"
      |       |-"postedBy":"user123"
      |
      @-nameBrandNike//topLevel
         |
         @-apparelTops//child
              |-"garmetSweater":"gray"
              |-"garmetTshirt":"pink"
              |-"postedBy":"user789"
```

I have several top level nodes in Firebase that also have child nodes underneath them. Inside the child nodes are the keys and values. I want to separate each topLevelNode `(RalphLauren,Nike)` into an array that contains it's child nodes `(apparelTops, apparelBottoms)` and then put them inside their own arrays.

How would I achieve something like this

```
var nameBrandNodes = [String]()
var apparelNodes = [[String]]()
var garmetNodes = [[String:Any]]()

nameBrandNodes = [RaplhLaurn, Nike]
apparelNodes = [[apparelTops, apparelBottoms], [apparelTops, apparelBottoms]]
garmetNodes = [["postedBy":"user123"], ["garmetSweater":"white"],["garmetTshirt":"blue"],["garmetShorts":"tan"], ["garmetJeans":"blue"], ["postedBy":"user789"], ["garmetSweater":"gray"], ["garmetTshirt":"pink"]]

//**EDIT** Jay's answer is CORRECT. I forgot to add this and added it after he answered
var nameBrandArrayOfDict = [[String:[String]]]

nameBrandArrayOfDict = [[nameBrandRalphLauren:[apparelTops,apparelBottoms], [[nameBrandNike:[apparelTops,apparelBottoms]]

//this is only necessary because sometimes there won't be an apparelBottomsNode or apparelTopsNode for e.g.
nameBrandArrayOfDict = [[nameBrandRalphLauren:[apparelTops], [[nameBrandNike:[apparelBottoms]]
```

Here is the code:

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()

var nameBrandNodes = [String]()
var apparelNodes = [[String]]()
var garmetNodes = [[String:Any]]()


let clothingRef = rootRef.child("clothing")

clothingRef?.observe(.childAdded, with: {
            (snapshot) in

       //nameBrandNodes now contains RalphLauren and Nike
       self.nameBrandNodes.append(snapshot.key)

       for nameBrand in self.nameBrandNodes{

                 let apparel = rootRef.child("clothing").child("nameBrand")
                 apparel.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                         (snapshot) in

                         for child in snapshot.children {
                             //what should I do in here?
                         }
        }
```

My end result is I'm using a vertical tableView and a horizontal collectionsView. I'm going to list the nameBrands inside the tableView, the apparel inside the collectionView, and the the garment items inside the collectionViews cells. I know how to put everything into the tableView and collectionView once it's separated, the problem I'm having is separating everything into different arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to throw down this answer as it addresses the question and may provide some direction and other options.

In this code we are populating a ClothingClass which contains the data that matches the data in Firebase. We also have two arrays bottomsArray and topsArray that keeps those items in separate arrays (per the question).

The concept here is that everything in Firebase is snapshot, and snapshots can contain other snapshots (i.e. a dictionary can contain other dictionaries).

We read in the entire node by .value and each high level node (the name brand) is the key to those nodes (the key in the key:value pair). The value on the other hand is also a snapshot i.e.

```
let apparelBottomsSnap = nameBrandSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "apparelBottoms")
```

Once we have those snapshots, assign their values to dictionaries and from there add the the ClothingClass as well as the separate array. There is no correlation between the ClothingClass and the arrays other than using the class is another way to organize the data in code for this example.

```
    class ClothingClass {
        var nameBrand = ""
        var bottomsDict = [String: Any]()
        var topsDict = [String: Any]()
    }

    var bottomsArray = [[String: Any]]()
    var topsArray = [[String: Any]]()
    var clothingArray = [ClothingClass]()

    let clothingRef = self.ref.child("clothing")
    clothingRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            let nameBrandSnap = child as! DataSnapshot //this is each name_brand
            let apparelBottomsSnap = nameBrandSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "apparelBottoms")
            let apparelTopsSnap = nameBrandSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "apparelTops")

            let bottomsDict = apparelBottomsSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let topsDict = apparelTopsSnap.value as! [String: Any]

            let aClothing = ClothingClass()
            aClothing.nameBrand = nameBrandSnap.key
            aClothing.bottomsDict = bottomsDict
            aClothing.topsDict = topsDict
            clothingArray.append(aClothing)

            bottomsArray.append(bottomsDict)
            topsArray.append(topsDict)
        }

        //for testing
        for c in clothingArray {
            let n = c.nameBrand
            let b = c.bottomsDict
            let t = c.topsDict

            print("n: \(n)")
            print("  b: \(b)")
            print("  t: \(t)")
        }

        print(topsArray)
        print(bottomsArray)
    })
```

The test loop at end end iterates over the array full of clothing classes and prints the properties of each one

```
n: name_brand_0
  b: ["garmetJeans": Blue, "garmetShorts": Pink, "postedBy": user_2]
  t: ["garmetShirt": blue, "garmetSweater": blue, "postedBy": user_0]
n: name_brand_1
  b: ["garmetJeans": Orange, "garmetShorts": Navy, "postedBy": user_3]
  t: ["garmetShirt": Green, "garmetSweater": Yellow, "postedBy": user_1]
```

and the print statement following prints the tops

```
[
  ["garmetShirt": blue, "garmetSweater": blue, "postedBy": user_0],
  ["garmetShirt": Green, "garmetSweater": Yellow, "postedBy": user_1]
]
```

and the bottoms

```
[
  ["garmetJeans": Blue, "garmetShorts": Pink, "postedBy": user_2],
  ["garmetJeans": Orange, "garmetShorts": Navy, "postedBy": user_3]
]
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE HELP!!! I've been stumped with this problem since yesterday night. Concentrating and figuring this out is difficult. I didn't know that I can take snapshot of snapshots :). I'm going to work through this code, apply it to what I'm using it for and get back to you. THANKS AGAIN!!!

Comment: Awesome question so I upvoted it! If the answer helped, please be sure to accept it so it can help others as well.

Comment: This is an AWESOME answer. I'll 100% up vote it. Gimme a few hours, I got you

Comment: I knew I forgot to add something. If you get a  chance I added an edit. Either way I'm accepting your answer as the correct one. Thanks again

Comment: @LanceSamaria I would suggest examining the ClothingClass in my answer. While you can certainly work with multiple arrays and dictionaries, an array of classes is often much simpler to maintain and easier to expand later if needed. Perhaps your edit would justify a different question that would revolve around leveraging a class structure to hold your data.

Comment: @Ja thanks. I'm going to try your class idea because it was something I had tried before I posted the question but it wasn't working. Now that I have more context I'll try it again, if I can't get it I'll post it as a new one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: this was a really really really great answer. I'm actually going to make changes to other parts of my app and use this as it's very easy. I wish I could update this again because I would. I'm sure there are thousands of devs who don't know about this process. Fantastic answer!